# visual studio installer project build from command line

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I have a project that suffers from a Visual Studio bug shown here

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=356321

It means that I can't build the installer project on my windows 7 machine
(the workaround presented doesn't work for me, regcap.exe crahses when I try to run it)

Now I plan to build the installer on a remote XP machine or in XP mode. Can I do this without installing the full Visual Studio? What is the command line to build from a .vdproj file?

Comment: The link is now broken

Answer (score 2):

The obvious choice that comes to mind is using msbuild, but unfortunately [it doesn't support building from .vdproj files](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=512134). Another option without using Visual Studio is [to use Team Foundation Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404859%28VS.80%29.aspx), if you have it installed or can afford to install it on one of your machines.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly work around: move to wix - http://wix.sourceforge.net/