# Building deployment project (.msi installer) from command line. Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, command-line

I installed the [deployment project support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549060/is-there-a-visual-studio-installer-project-type-for-visual-studio-2019) add-on, to my VS2019, and can build setup/msi successfully from the GUI.
I tried to run the project building from the command line:

"C:...\msbuild.exe" myinstaller.vdproj -p:Configuration=Release

It failed (unable to load the project: bad data at root level).

Is now there in the VS Community edition an option to build deployment projects from a command line,
or it is still an option of [higher level studios only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879243/visual-studio-installer-project-build-from-command-line), or I'm doing something incorrect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019)

"For build-related tasks, it's recommended that you use MSBuild instead of devenv. For more information, see MSBuild command-line reference."

was misleading ( me :) ).

One must use devenv. Just that.
Works (while MSBuild doesn't).
Closed.